# Style to impact only div where being declared

Tags: html, css

I have a popup where I print some message to user and inside I use different styles than generally used in the page. F.e.

```
<div id='myPopup'>
    <style type="text/css">
    table,div,td
    {
        font-size:8pt;
        border-color:black;
    }
    </style> 

    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is, those style impact all the page changing my tables etc. behind popup. Of course, I could right classes and use them in my popup `<table class='someClass'/>` but maybe there is another way?

Comment: Either put the whole popup in an Iframe, or make the styles more specific, for instance `#myPopup table, #myPopup div, #myPopup td{ ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the div id to your css. Something like this should work:

```
<div id='myPopup'>
    <style type="text/css">
        #myPopup table,#myPopup div,#myPopup td{
            font-size:8pt;
            border-color:black;
        }
    </style> 
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```